# punctuation following "Likewise"

Tags: punctuation

I'm wondering whether or not "Likewise" should be followed by a comma in the following dialogue:

> A: Hello, you must be Peter.
>
> B: And you must be Sam.
>
> A: That's right. Welcome to Boston.
>
> B: Thank you. It's such a pleasure to meet you.
>
> A:  **Likewise,** all the staff at PC Mart are looking forward to meeting you and your team.

Could "likewise" be taken to mean "with the same pleasure" in the above and the use of a comma justified?

Comment: They should be two separate sentences.

Comment: *Likewise* in that context is its own independent clause, and it should be treated as such. Punctuate it with a semicolon, dash, or period. Or put an *and* after the comma.

Comment: @JasonBassford I've edited the question. Please see the above.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change my earlier comment.

Comment: If "likewise" means "with the same pleasure," wouldn't it form a unit with the following "all the staff at PC Mart ..." and justify the comma?